# Decrypt method from java to php

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes

I have this method in java that I would like to rewrite it in php.

```
public static final byte[] keyValue = new byte[] { 'T', 'h', 'e', 'B', 'e',
        's', 't', 'S', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' };
public final static String ALGO = "AES";

public static String Dcrypt(String encryptedData) {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
    // Key key = generateKey();
    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decordedValue = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedData);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
        decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return decryptedValue;
}
```

what methods i should use in php to achieve that.

some sources:

- http://pastebin.com/UnD5pgSB
- http://aesencryption.net/

decrypted password is: password

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: here is a link of my first attempt. http://pastebin.com/UnD5pgSB

Comment: Please edit your original post and paste your code there so it is preserved for future SO visitors.

Comment: General advice: **Always use a fully qualified Cipher string.** `Cipher.getInstance("AES");` may result in different ciphers depending on the default security provider. It most likely defaults to `Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");`, but that doesn't always have to be true.

Comment: **Never use [ECB mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using code from http://aesencryption.net/

Change inputkey and blocksize to suite your needs.

http://pastebin.com/DbzY8Q0F

Comment: Don't! The code on aesencryption.net is horribly insecure.

Comment: please propose a solution for my problem then instead of criticizing only.

Comment: https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption